Circles of the Lighthouse theorem
I was doing some research on the Morley theorem for a school project when I came across the Lighthouse theorem in Richard K. Guy's paper:

Two sets of lines at equal angular distances, one set through each of the points B, C, intersect in n² points that are the vertices of n regular n-gons. The circumcircles of the n-gons each pass through B and C.

When I put it into Geogebra, I noticed that no matter which circumcircle I take and invert it with respect to another circumcircle, I always get one of the circles of the n-gons. I managed to prove this conjecture, and my question is whether this set of circles have any other interesting properties and I'm also curious if they have any connection to some other theorems.

Suggestion. There are definitely connections to geometric aspects of complex numbers. Are you aware of linear-fractional transforms of the complex plane (they map circles and lines to circles and lines) and properties of the complex log function $w=Log z$ which maps a polar grids in the $z$  plane to a rectangular grid in the $w$ plane?

Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I'm not really familiar with complex numbers in general, but I'll try looking into them.
